# Acquire position on Sony Xperia (Android 5.1.1) gets timeout expired

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, sony-xperia

I am trying to acquire the position with WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition and sometimes I get the Timeout expired error especially on Sony Xperia (Android 5.1.1 - WebView 43.0.2357.121).

`WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(successFunc, failFunc,{
                          enableHighAccuracy: false, // tried with true also
                          timeout: 10 * 1000,
                          maximumAge: 5000
                    });`

I also tried:

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunc, failFunc,{
                  enableHighAccuracy: false,
                  timeout: 10 * 1000,
                  maximumAge: 5000
            });`

and the same error appears.

On Huawei P6 (Android 4.4.2, Chrome 30) everything works fine.

Is there any workaround this?

Thanks!

Comment: Pure Cordova geolocation also fails. Permission issues? May be location services not enabled in the device settings?

Comment: All permissions are given, location is turned on... Like I said sametimes is working sometimes is not...